# regular expression for brackets and strings inside it

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a JavaScript regular expression that allow me to remove any text in brackets and include the brackets itself.

Example:

```
"hello world ( some Text and Number here)"
```

And I want to trim `( some Text and Number here)` and get the result as:

```
"hello world"
```

Comment: Would you ever get nested parentheses?

Comment: not really, but its good to know the regex for that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this one:

```
\(.*?\)
```

Actual js might be like dis:

```
var a = "hello world ( someText and Number here)";
a = a.replace(/\(.*?\)/, "");
```

Comment: Make sure to apply it over and over until it doesn't change the string, if nested brackets may appear